# Why <img> and <b> tags are not escaped by Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, escaping, xss, sanitization

I am using Angular 13 for my development.

Recently I created a simple angular form with a user input field, I tried providing different kinds of inputs, where I saw that providing input as `<b>Hack</b><img src="some_url" >` was working and is not escaped by angular.

I tried doing the POC on the same and created a live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kidre6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts),
but could find out that using angular's DOM Sanitizer service also these inputs are not being escaped by angular.

For reference,

**.ts**

```
import { Component, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  userName = 'Angular';

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  onSave(): void {
    console.log('save clicked api call');
    this.sanitizeUserName();
  }

  sanitizeUserName(): string {
    const domSanitize = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(1, this.userName);
    console.log('sanitized text/html', domSanitize);
    return domSanitize;
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<form #userForm="ngForm">
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName" name="username" />

  <div>
    <span>View : </span>
    <div [innerHTML]="userName"></div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="button" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Angular sanitize also imgs. I imagine that your problem is with an external image, you should use as argument 4, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/SecurityContext). You can also use the methods [bypassSecurityTrustHtml](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize) (or bypassSecurityTrustUrl). Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enz96e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) -you can pass the hamburger imagen using `1` but you can not use an external image if not use `4`-

Comment: @Eliseo I can see passing `<b>Hackwrone1</b><img src="link_to_external_img" >` using with 4 as well. If you try to put eg #2 from the project in the input field, you will be able to see the imgae.

Comment: @Eliseo please see the edit question, I have added the image. with 1 & 4 both

Comment: try using `return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.userName)` (NOTE: the return type is [SafeHtml](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/SafeHtml)

Comment: But why are we using bypassSecurityTrustHTML ? our focus is to escape the HTML tags i.e sanitize HTML tags such that the browser read as a text rather than code. Please correct me if I am wrong, bypassSecurityTrustHTML will by pass the HTML that is provided by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will automatically sanitize any input that is passed as an attribute, but it will not escape it. The sanitizer removes potentially dangerous elements (like script tags) to prevent some XSS attacks, but leaves most of them intact.
If you're curious, you can look at the [tests of Angular's HTML sanitization code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14.2.0/packages/core/test/sanitization/html_sanitizer_spec.ts).

Assuming that the user name is saved on a remote server when the form is sent, you must sanitize and / or escape the values there.
Servers should never trust the client to perform some actions, since an attacker can easily bypass them.

In case you have a Node.js backend or want to display the sanitized value in the browser,
the [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) package performs a similar task that Angular's DOM sanitizer does, but you get more control over it.

You could also consider putting some more constraints on the user names by only allowing specific patterns. You can use the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) to specify a regular expression for the input so users aren't even able to input anything that will later be escaped or sanitized by the server.